# Nginx proxy cache passes GET instead of HEAD to the upstream

Tags: caching, nginx

I configured nginx as a reverse proxy of my application server. When I turn on the proxy cache, it passes GET instead of HEAD to the upstream application server. I've searched google but there's no feasible solution. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

We changed the nginx source code as following:

`static char* gx_http_proxy_merge_loc_conf(ngx_conf_t *cf, void *parent, void *child) {
  ...
  // conf->upstream.cache_methods |= NGX_HTTP_GET|NGX_HTTP_HEAD;
  conf->upstream.cache_methods |= NGX_HTTP_GET;
  ...
}`

It really works, but this solution is so ugly. We are still keeping on finding a more elegant solution...